# Doubling up of cells when loading a vc/xib again

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting duplicate cells every time I exit this xib and go back to it.

Lets say I added two ingredients, rice and sugar. If I exit and return, I have doubles of the ingredients. This happens every time I load this controller.

I think this is the faulty code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:YES];
    //fixed doubling up of ingredients by addingn else before the other if and corresponding bracket  Nov 13 falcon
if (self.groceryList) {

    self.arrIngredients = [((MealIdeaAppDelegate*)MI_SHARED_DELEGATE).dbCommunicator getMyGroceryListIngredients:self.groceryList.groceryListID];

    NSLog(@"data %@ ",self.groceryList.groceryListID);
    self.title = self.groceryList.groceryListName;
    txtfListName.text = self.groceryList.groceryListName;
        //Added else Nov 13 falcon
}else if ([self.groceryList.groceryListName caseInsensitiveCompare:kDeafaultGroceryListName] == 0) {
        [txtfListName setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }

        [tblvGroceryListDetail reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have added the values to the  array and when u exit and return, viewWillAppear: is called again which adds the same data to the array once again, Hence doubling the data, For this you should do the code in viewDidLoad: method

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
    {
       // do the code done in viewWillAppear here
    }
```

Comment: you are correct, that was the issue.  I'm learning, so could you please explain why this was happening?  Thanks!

Comment: just rebooted the application and doubled all the cells now, the issue when switching with controllers is over, but now its when it boots into that controller.  I am amending the post with the new code

Comment: whenever you return to a new view controller viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: are called. But viewDidLoad: is called only when a view controller loads for the first Time. This is the answer for your first comment. I am not clear about your second comment, so would like you to explain it a bit more.